# Segue between navigation controllers doesn't seem to push the stack, but back button works

Tags: ios, swift

I have a segue between two navigation controllers (`A` -> `B`). Using the buttons, I am able to navigate between these controllers seamlessly. The issue is that in controller B, I would like to access controller A, which is lower on the stack. I was trying this:

```
self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0] as! A
```

This gives me an error because it says I cannot cast `B` to `A`. Inspecting the size of `self.navigationController!.viewControllers` shows that it has count `1`. Where did `A` go on the stack?

The segue type is "Show (e.g. Push)"

Comment: println(self.parentViewController?.childViewControllers) what's the out put of this code ?

Comment: `[<MyApp.B: 0x7ff1a15ec400>]`

Comment: I think that if you try to push more then one that it will work. and A is not in viewControllers stack since A is a root view controller. Since I just think that it is an answer :)

Comment: How do I access the root view controller from `B`?

Comment: Do you actually mean your segue is between two navigation controllers, or between (A.rootViewController -> B)? A isn't going to be on its own stack.

Comment: A is rootViewController and u can access it via navcontroller.rootviewcontroller

Comment: `A` and `B` are both embedded in a navigation controller. The version `UINavigationView` I'm linking against does not have a method or property `rootViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't really have a segue between two navigation controllers. If your app is a standard master-detail application, you actually have a segue between `A.rootViewController` → `B` (where `A` and `B` are the navigation controllers), and that the code you're referring to is in `B.rootViewController` (e.g. "DetailViewController"), not `B`.

As such, `self` is `B.rootViewController`, `self.navigationController` is `B`, and so `self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0]` is `B.rootViewController`, not `A.rootViewController` as you expect.

Try this:

```
    let A = self.navigationController!.parentViewController! as! UINavigationController
    NSLog("%@", A.viewControllers[0])
```